# wrong eigenvectors using zgeev.f

Tags: fortran, lapack, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm trying to diagonalize a non-hermitian matrix using the subroutine zgeev in lapack. But checking the right eigenvectors and the left eigenvectors it is possible to see that they are incorrect. Does anyone know why? I checked the eigenvalues and they are corrects.

```
program complex_diagonalization  
implicit none
integer,parameter :: N=4
integer::i,j
integer, parameter:: LWMAX=1000
integer,parameter :: LDA=N,LDVL=N,LDVR=N
real(kind=8),parameter::q=-dsqrt(3.0d0)
integer :: INFO,LWORK
real(kind=8) :: RWORK(2*N)
complex*16 :: B(LDA,N),VL(LDVL,N),VR(LDVR,N),W(N),WORK(2*N)
external::zgeev
!matrix defining

B(1,1)=0.0d0;  B(1,2)=-1.0d0;  B(1,3)=0.0d0; B(1,4) =0.0d0 
B(2,1)=0.0d0; B(2,2)=0.0d0;  B(2,3)=-2.0d0;  B(2,4) =0.0d0
B(3,1)=-1.0d0;  B(3,2)=0.0d0; B(3,3)=0.0d0;  B(3,4) =q
B(4,1)=0.0d0;  B(4,2)=q;  B(4,3)=0.0d0;      B(4,4) =0.0d0 

LWORK=-1
CALL ZGEEV('V','V',N,B,LDA,W,VL,LDVL,VR,LDVR,WORK,LWORK,RWORK,INFO)
LWORK=Max(LWMAX,INT(WORK(1)))
CALL ZGEEV('V','V',N,B,LDA,W,VL,LDVL,VR,LDVR,WORK,2*N,RWORK,INFO)

IF( INFO.GT.0 ) THEN
 WRITE(*,*)'The algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.'
 STOP
END IF
!eigenvalues
do i=1,N
WRITE(*,*)W(i)
enddo

write(*,*)
write(*,*)
! eigenvalues and right eigenvectors
do i=1,N
write(*,*) 'eigenvalue->', w(i)
write(*,*)
WRITE(*,*) 'right eigvector->', (VR(i,j),j=1,N)
write(*,*)
ENDDO
write(*,*)
write(*,*)
!eigenvalues and left eigenvectors
do i=1,N
WRITE(*,*) 'eigenvalue->', w(i)
write(*,*)
WRITE(*,*) 'left eigvector->', (Vl(i,j),j=1,N)
write(*,*)
ENDDO

end
```

This is the result for eigenvalues and eigenvectors

```
(-2.00000000000000,-1.110223024625157E-016)
 (1.00000000000000,1.73205080756888)
 (1.00000000000000,-1.73205080756888)
 (0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 
 eigenvalue-> (-2.00000000000000,-1.110223024625157E-016)
 
 right eigvector-> (0.288675134594813,8.847089727481716E-017)
 (-0.144337567297406,-0.250000000000000) (-0.144337567297406,-0.250000000000000)
 (0.866025403784438,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 eigenvalue-> (1.00000000000000,1.73205080756888)
 
 right eigvector-> (0.577350269189626,2.289834988289385E-016)
 (-0.288675134594813,0.500000000000000)
 (0.577350269189626,0.000000000000000E+000)
 (0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 eigenvalue-> (1.00000000000000,-1.73205080756888)
 
 right eigvector-> (0.577350269189626,0.000000000000000E+000)
 (0.577350269189626,0.000000000000000E+000)
 (-0.288675134594813,0.500000000000000)
 (0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 eigenvalue-> (0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 right eigvector-> (0.500000000000000,2.463307335887066E-016)
 (-0.250000000000000,-0.433012701892219) (-0.250000000000000,-0.433012701892219)
 (-0.500000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 
 
 eigenvalue-> (-2.00000000000000,-1.110223024625157E-016)
 
 left eigvector-> (0.288675134594813,2.949029909160572E-017)
 (-0.144337567297406,-0.250000000000000) (-0.144337567297406,-0.250000000000000)
 (0.866025403784438,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 eigenvalue-> (1.00000000000000,1.73205080756888)
 
 left eigvector-> (0.577350269189626,3.157196726277789E-016)
 (-0.288675134594813,0.500000000000000)
 (0.577350269189626,0.000000000000000E+000)
 (0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 eigenvalue-> (1.00000000000000,-1.73205080756888)
 
 left eigvector-> (0.577350269189626,0.000000000000000E+000)
 (0.577350269189626,0.000000000000000E+000)
 (-0.288675134594813,0.500000000000000)
 (0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 eigenvalue-> (0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)
 
 left eigvector-> (0.500000000000000,1.491862189340054E-016)
 (-0.250000000000000,-0.433012701892219) (-0.250000000000000,-0.433012701892219)
 (-0.500000000000000,0.000000000000000E+000)
```

Even the right eigenvectors doesn't satisfy the condition H*v(j)=lambda(j)*v(j).

Comment: The above code does not compile - you haven't declared lwmax. Could you please post the code you are actually using.

Comment: Hi Ian. I forget to add an integer parameter where LWMAX = 1000.

Comment: OK - the i'th eigenvector is stored in the i'th columns of VR, but you are printing out the i'th *row*. Could you please show the code you are using to check the eigenvectors.

Comment: I couldn't make a code to check the eigenvectors. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: An eigenvector solves `H.v=l.v`, so to check them you can just calculate `H.v` and see if it's equal (to within some tolerance) to `l.v`.